# Preprocessor macros in static library

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

In a Objective-C project I am using a static library, compilation of this static library depends on some preprocessor macros to be set.

When I set these macros in the project depending on the library the library does not see them. But when I set them in the library project it does work.

Since I want to reuse this library for other projects, I require to set the preprocessor macros for each project depending on the library separately. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: How did you set them in the project? Preprocessor Macros section? I'm finding it not to work

Comment: See the selected answer, it was not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preprocessor maros only have any meaning at compile-time, so any library you build will be specific to the values of these preprocessor macros at the time you built the library. You will either need lots of different versions of your library, built with the different possible values of your preprocessor macros, or you could switch to using a different method to control the behaviour of your library code which will work at run-time, e.g. setting some appropriate parameters through the library API.

Comment: There is no other way to solve this issue? Structure of classes depend on these macros.

Comment: I'm afraid not - you either define these things at build time or at run time. Currently you define them at build time, hence your current limitations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se, but something interesting I discovered while struggling with this same issue.

I have a static library (`MyLib`) that contains a header for logging (`Log.h`). I have an application project (`MyApp`) that uses `MyLib`. `Log.h` has some resemblance of this:

```
#ifdef LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
#   define LogDebug(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else 
#   define LogDebug(...)
#endif
```

In `MyApp` build settings, I can use the preprocessor macro `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG` to successfully turn off and on logging. This works when I use `LogDebug()` in source files found in `MyApp`. However, the `MyLib` source files that use `LogDebug()` are not affected by the `MyApp` build settings. I have to use the `MyLib` build settings to affect `LogDebug()` within the `MyLib` source files.

I am pretty sure I know what is happening but I'd be open to correction. Below is the scenario where `MyApp` defines `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG` in build settings (enabling debugging) and `MyLib` does not define it (disabling it).

When `MyApp` builds, it first compiles `MyLib` where all of the `LogDebug()` are replaced within the `MyLib` source files as `no-op` (since `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG` was not defined). After `MyLib` is compiled, `MyApp` is compiled and all of the `LogDebug()` methods within `MyApp` source are replaced with `NSLog()` statements because `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG` was defined in the build settings.

Comment: similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758187/enabling-ifdef-macro-used-in-the-static-library?rq=1